# Bonobo git server не корректно работает с русскими именами в файлах

Tags: git, 1с, bonobo

Всем привет!

На работе имеется windows server 2008 r2, ведем разработку на 1с. Вводим Git. Доступа к интернету у сервера нет, поэтому публичные сервера вроде GitHub использовать нет возможности. Поэтому был установлен [сервер Bonobo](https://bonobogitserver.com). В целом, он отлично подходит, реализует основные функции, имеет веб-интерфейс, быстро разворачивается. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при скачивании через кнопку "Загрузить" в основном меню или в меню ветки, в папке с файлами пусто. Потом стало понятно, что это связано с тем, что файлы имеют русские имена, все английские файлы хорошо добавляются. Функция достаточно критичная, Поэтому вопрос, может кто с этим сталкивался и можно ли как-то это исправить.

Перейти на английское именование файлов - не вариант.

Из серверов для windows ставил GitStack - не понравился в использовании.